# NETCONF vs RESTCONF Vs gRPC

Tags: network-programming, grpc, router, ietf-restconf, netconf

For network automation, I see that NETCONF, RESTCONF and gRPC are available. Can someone tell me which one should be chosen for a typical router and respective use cases.

Can you please share the known issues or challenges with respective approach in terms of implementation.